# How to send message from a logic app to dead letter queue (azure bus service)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to send message to  Dead letter Queue  from a logic app.

[image: logic app send message connector configuration]

But I am getting following  exception.

[image: exception]

P.S : I can send message to any  normal queue from logic app. I am using free tier subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an API and protocol perspective, the DLQ is mostly similar to any other queue, except that messages can only be submitted via the dead-letter operation of the parent entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#the-dead-letter-queue

The [Dead-letter the message in a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#dead-letter-the-message-in-a-queue) operation moves the message to the Dead-Letter Queue.

[image]

Comment: I have tried above solution but I am getting following error 
Failed to dead-letter the message with the lock token 'e7752b96-1866-485c-89e4-86c074c33f43'. The lock on the message has been lost.\r\nclientRequestId:

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you can use [Dead-letter the message in a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#dead-letter-the-message-in-a-queue) action in your logic app and **go to your queue on portal, set the "lock duration" with 5 minutes.**